# PC stalls and eventually crashes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, chkdsk, raid-5

I am home for the holidays and my father is having computer issues I was asked to fix, but am unsure of how to fix the issue.

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition that has 5 Western Digital hard drives in RAID-5, plus an SSD for the system. Whenever I start the PC it does one of two things: (1) it tries to launch Windows and fails, so it stalls and I have to manually shut it down, (2) after restarting it runs `CHKDSK` which gives me the following errors:

```
Correcting errors in the BadClusterFile
Replacing bad cluster in log file
CHKDSK was unable to adjust the size of the log file
Adding 76 bad clusters to the BadClusterFile
CHKDSK discovered free space market as allocated in the volume bitmap
Windows has made corrections to the file system
```

After this, Windows launches normally and I have access to the files on the hard drives. So I run the Western Digital "Data LifeGuard Diagnostics" (DLGDIAG) on the hard drives. Quick tests find nothing, but extended test on disk 6 has a never enting "expected time" and then crashes with the error message "Too many bad sectors".

Eventually, after using the PC as normal, Windows crashes and task manager says all the programs are not responding, at which point I can only manually shut it off and restart.

From reading other posts, it seems like the solution is to replace disk 6 and remake the RAID setup. However is there anything I could try to do before buying a new hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

According to the chkdsk you do have a hard drive heading south. I would make a image backup as soon as possible. I am a little confused about you drive configuration. As a rule you can't run DLGDIAG on drives behind a RAID controller as it won't recognize the individual drives. Can you go in to a little more detail on the drives and controller?

The boot drive is ssd and the "Data" drive is the RAID5 WD's? Who's RAID Controller?